# how to print an php array into a HTML table

Tags: php, html, sql

> before I start I know there are more advanced methods but this is for
> a class project and I have to develop it in HTML and PHP... Im already
> using some Bootstrap things in my code and Im not sure it will not
> cause me trouble with my teacher

so I have this project  and I need help because Im tired of hitting my head against the brick wall...

I have to create a search engine page to catch one of 3 (or all of them) posibl values that are user ID, Contract ID and Local ID (adress of sorts) I developed this PHP code that in Todd Howards famous words "It works... it just works"

```
<?php

//inicio de conexion y verificacion de errores//    
    $con = mysqli_connect ("localhost" , "root" , "");

    if (!$con) 
    {
        echo 'No conecta al servidor';
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'estrella'))
    {
        echo 'No conecta a base de datos';
    }

    //Recupera valor de busqueda//
    $Bcedula = $_GET['Bcedula'];
    $Blocal = $_GET['Blocal'];
    $Bcontrato = $_GET['Bcontrato'];

    $min_length =3;
    //funcion busqueda por cedula//

    switch (true) 
    {
        case (strlen($Bcedula) >= $min_length):
        $Bcedula = htmlspecialchars($Bcedula);
        $rawresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE (Ncedula LIKE '%".$Bcedula."%')");
        break;
    
        case (strlen($Blocal) >= $min_length):
        $Blocal = htmlspecialchars($Blocal);
        $rawresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE (Nlocal LIKE '%".$Blocal."%')");
    
        case (strlen($Bcontrato) >= $min_length):
        $Bcontrato = htmlspecialchars($Bcontrato);
        $rawresults = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contrato WHERE (Ncontrato LIKE '%".$Bcontrato."%')");
    
        default: 
            echo 'error dato no encontrado';
            break;
    }

header("Refresh:1; url=busqueda.html");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($rawresults) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
             
            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($rawresults)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop
                
                echo("<p> Contrato, Cedula, Nombres, Apellidos, Local, Nit, CC, Direccion, Telefono, Valor total, Fecha inicio, N. Cuoas.</p></br>"); 
                echo "<p>" .$results['Ncontrato'].", ".$results['Ncedula'].", ".$results['Nombre1']." ".$results['Nombre2']." ".$results['Apellido1']." ".$results['Apellido2'].", ".$results['Nlocal'].", ".$results['Nnit'].", ".$results['Ncamara'].", ".$results['Direccion'].", ".$results['Telefono'].", ".$results['Vcontrato'].", ".$results['Vfechainicio'].", ".$results['Vcuotas'].                 
                "</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
             echo mysqli_error($con);
            }
             
        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }
    
header("url=busqueda.html")       

?>
```

it prints an ugly 2 strings of code and Im working now on making it a table... and here comes the issue... I have an Html page that calls upon the php and it looks like this

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Busqueda</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
#Table_01 {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-image: url(images/Busqueda.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Busqueda.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1109" height="471" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <form method="get" action="busqueda.php">
            <input style="width:354px; height:20px" type="text" name="Bcedula"></td>
            <input style="width:354px; height:20px" type="text" name="Nlocal"></td>
            <input style="width:354px; height:20px" type="text" name="Bcontrato"></td>
    </form>

    <form mehod="post" action="busqueda.php">
            <input style="width:912px; height:283" type="search" name="Rbusqueda">      
    </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and it looks like this
[Search Engine made by me... please dont laugh too hard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMJm1.png)

so... here is the deal I tried to make it a little better and got some bootstrap code here and there... and made me a table with a jumbotron and a table... the code looks like this

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
        <table class="table table-hover"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th># de Contrato</th>
                    <th># de Cedula</th>
                    <th>Primer Nombre</th>
                    <th>Segundo Nombre</th>
                    <th>Primer Apellido</th>
                    <th>Segundo Apellido</th>
                    <th>Local</th>
                    <th>Nit</th>
                    <th>Camara de Comercio</th>
                    <th>Direccion</th>
                    <th>Telefono</th>
                    <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                    <?php
include 'busqueda.php';
             
            foreach($results as $row) : ?>
                            
 
                    <td><?php echo $row->Ncontrato ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Ncedula ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Nombre1 ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Nombre2 ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Apellido1 ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Apellido2 ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Nlocal ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Nnit ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Ncamara ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Direccion ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Telefono ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Vcontrato ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Vfechainicio ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->Vcuotas ?></td>     
        
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

it goes in the HTML in place of the Rbusqueda form that I was trying to create before
but it doesnt work and Im starting to go crazy... so can anyone help me out here please?... pretty please?

Comment: Lets start from the top... First of all you are echoing out '<p>....</p>' instead of saving it to an array or something with the name $results.. and then looping through that and add some **<td>** elements to the table.

Comment: Your <p> tags should be <td> tags

Comment: You are saving mysqli_fetch_array to $results, I missed that..... but what it looks like your really trying to do is save the echos to an array and then loop that array later with foreach($results as $row)... right?

Comment: yes thats what Im trying to do but I dont know how

Comment: I'm guessing the first section of code is in your busqueda.php file?

Comment: Right after include 'busqueda.php'; before you try looping through **$results** dump out $results - var_dump($results);.... Does results have data in it? Is it working to that point?

Comment: not working and now it give me "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"